# Under an Xampp install, I modify the apache httpd-vhosts.conf file and then my Apache server will not start

Tags: apache, virtualhost, xampp, windows-7

I have read all the articles but still must be doing something wrong... I modified the httpd-vhosts.conf file to access the project I am working on... I have tried many different configurations and none work. My apache service will not start (I am on Windows 7)... any ideas would be helpful - here is the code I added to the conf file:

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
ServerName localhost


DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/socengv1"
ServerName socengv1.local

I have also tried this with NameVirtualHost *:80       command with no difference to note.

Answer (score 2):

First;

add port to your ServerName

```
< VirtualHost *:80 >  
    DocumentRoot C:/server/htdocs  
    ServerName localhost:80   
< /VirtualHost >
```

Second Chance, give a different name to ServerName and add the ServerName  to the windows hosts file, this is located in “C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts”.
Open the file in Notepad and simply add;

```
127.0.0.1       localhost  
127.0.0.1       urServerName
```

Also add to check errors;

```
ErrorLog        ErrorLog @rel_logfiledir@/urServerName-error_log
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link and I you will find the solution in my case it was SQL

[How to Solve Port 80 Problems When Running Apache on Windows](http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/)

Answer (score 0):

Remember, logs directory must exist before start server.